# Dynamic text boxes binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to make a form of sorts where the user will have the option to press a button to dynamically add more text boxes, with each text box to contain the path of a directory to exclude from a search. This is relatively trivial using code-behind, but my problem is doing it in proper MVVM.

The general markup for the structure is:

```
<ScrollViewer >
    <StackPanel>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
            <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                    Content="+"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Clicking the button will add a new `DockPanel` with a `TextBox` and `Button` to the `StackPanel`. All buttons but the bottom-most will change to a minus sign. How can I somehow bind to the text of all the text boxes?

As an aside, once/if I get this working, would it be better to make it into its own component?

Comment: I'll recommend you using MVVM when it helps you and make things easier. If the solution is easier in codebehind just go for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick pseudo-code to get you started:

cs (view model):

```
// INotifyPropertyChanged if you need, as well as full-properties with notification
public class Item
{
    public string Text {get; set;}
}

public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

void OnCommandAdd() => Items.Add(new Item());
```

xaml (view):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The idea is to use control able to display list (e.g. `ItemsControl`) and collection of items in view model. Adding new element to view is done by adding item to that collection.

All `TextBox`es will have `Text` bound to corresponding property of item.